# How make side by side div elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i have in my react app component with list of events. I would like to display them side by side, not one by one. I was trying to do this with flexbox but something its wrong. Thanks for help.

```html
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}


.place-list {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 20%;

}
```

```html
return (
    <div className="flex-container">
      <div className="place-list">
        {props.items.map((place) => (
          <PlaceItem
            key={place.id}
            id={place.id}
            image={place.image}
            title={place.title}
            description={place.description}
            address={place.address}
            creatorId={place.creator}
            coordinates={place.location}
            onDelete={props.onDeletePlace}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The flex container needs to the the *parent* of the flex elements.

Your flex container is the *grandparent* of the elements you want to be the flex elements. It has only one child.

The element with the class `place-list` needs to the the output of each `<PlaceItem>` not a single wrapper around all of them.

Answer (score 0):

`PlaceItem` is the child element of an element with the class name `place-list`, not `flex-container`.
Try this:

```css
.place-list{
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your CSS should look like this:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* You could also align left, right, ect. */
}


.place-list {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 20%;

}
```

This would align your child elements in a row.

Comment: The child element (singular) is already in a row (of one item). The change you propose just horizontally aligns it to the center.

Comment: You should define the size of your .flex-container. The default is set to 0. Codepen example:   https://codepen.io/M-Coder/pen/gOmpexV